# UWP : Links does not work in PDF after generating a PDF with ReportWriter (SyncFusion)

Tags: pdf, uwp, syncfusion

I'm using a UWP application to generate a .pdf file from an .rdlc template file with Syncfusion components. I can generate the pdf from the rdlc template file but all the links in the pdf (text or image) does not work. The links work if I generate an html file but not in pdf file. Here is the code :

```
var pdfFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(String.Concat("Order-", this.Model.SaleReference, ".pdf"), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (var stream = await pdfFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    using (var outstream = stream.AsStreamForWrite())
    {
        var assembly = typeof(FinalizeViewModel).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

        var reportStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("UWP.OrderModule.Reports.Test.rdlc");

        var writer = new ReportWriter(reportStream)
        {
            ExportMode = Syncfusion.ReportWriter.ExportMode.Local
        };

        writer.Save(outstream, WriterFormat.PDF);

        outstream.Dispose();
    }
}

await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdfFile);
```

I also try with this code but the result is the same :

```
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(String.Concat("Order-", this.Model.SaleReference, ".pdf"), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

using (var stream = await WindowsRuntimeStorageExtensions.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(file))
{
    var assembly = typeof(FinalizeViewModel).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

    var reportStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("UWP.OrderModule.Reports.Test.rdlc");

    var writer = new ReportWriter(reportStream)
    {
        ReportProcessingMode = Syncfusion.ReportWriter.ProcessingMode.Local,
        ExportMode = Syncfusion.ReportWriter.ExportMode.Local
    };

    writer.Save(stream, WriterFormat.PDF);
}

await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdfFile);
```

What is wrong ? Is there a problem in the ReportWriter class (Syncfusion.RdllO.RdllOExportEngine class) ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Syncfusion ReportWriter don't have support for exporting report as PDF with hyperlink option. We will consider to include this feature in any of our upcoming release.